# Trigger to clone Attachment from Opportunity to Contract not working as expected

Tags: apex, trigger

I have a trigger which looks to take the Attachments from all Opportunities which have at least 1 Quote record (aka 'DataSchedule') to the Opportunity.ContractId once a Contract has been related to the Opportunity.

My code compiles however, it does not run as expected. I am not getting any System.debug logs for row 27 or 31 (the last 2 debugs), so I think the issue starts from row 24 onwards.

Please can you advise me what I am doing incorrectly here?

Many thanks

```
trigger CopyAttachmentsFromOpportunitiesWithDataSchedulesToContracts on Opportunity (after update, after insert) {

    Set<Id> opportunitiesToEvaluate = new Set<Id>(); 
    List<Attachment> attachmentsToClone = new List<Attachment>();

    for (Opportunity opp : Trigger.new) {
        if ((Trigger.isInsert && opp.ContractId != NULL) || (Trigger.isUpdate && (opp.ContractId != NULL && Trigger.oldMap.get(opp.Id).ContractId == NULL))) {
        opportunitiesToEvaluate.add(opp.Id); // Opportunity was not related to a contract but now is related to a contract
        System.debug('Count of this *OPPORTUNITY SET* is: ' + opportunitiesToEvaluate.size());  
        }
    }   

    if (!opportunitiesToEvaluate.isEmpty()) {

        // query only Opportunities which have >=1 Quote__c child records       
        Map<Id, Quote__c> oppToQuoteMap = new Map<Id, Quote__c>([SELECT Opportunity__c FROM Quote__c WHERE Opportunity__c IN : opportunitiesToEvaluate]); 

        System.debug('Count of this *MAP (oppToQuoteMap)* is: ' + oppToQuoteMap.size());

        // store the ContractId of all such Opportunities 
        Map<Id, Opportunity> oppToContractMap = new Map<Id, Opportunity>([SELECT Id, ContractId FROM Opportunity WHERE Id IN : oppToQuoteMap.keySet()]);
        System.debug('Count of this *MAP* (oppToContractMap) is: ' + oppToQuoteMap.size());

        List<Attachment> attachmentsRelatedToOpps = [SELECT Id, ParentId FROM Attachment WHERE ParentId IN : oppToQuoteMap.keySet()]; 

        for (Attachment file : attachmentsRelatedToOpps) {
            System.debug('Count of the *ATTACHMENT SET* is: ' + attachmentsRelatedToOpps.size());   
            Attachment newFile = file.clone(); 
            newFile.ParentId = oppToContractMap.get(file.ParentId).ContractId; 
            attachmentsToClone.add(newFile); 
            System.debug('Count of the *ATTACHMENT TO CLONE SET* is: ' + attachmentsToClone.size()); 
        }
    }

    insert attachmentsToClone; 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so here is the code that is working now as expected:

It seems that one needs to explicitly SELECT Name and Body attributes from the SOQL to populate the list of Attachments. I didn't think this was required because the .clone() method is being used, so I will investigate this further.

I also changed line 32 to be 'IN : setQuoteOppIds', I think that was an omission from Nilesh.

```
trigger CopyAttachmentsFromOpportunitiesWithDataSchedulesToContracts on Opportunity (after update, after insert) {

    Set<Id> opportunitiesToEvaluate = new Set<Id>(); 
    List<Attachment> attachmentsToClone = new List<Attachment>();

    for (Opportunity opp : Trigger.new) {
        if ((Trigger.isInsert && opp.ContractId != NULL) || (Trigger.isUpdate && (opp.ContractId != NULL && Trigger.oldMap.get(opp.Id).ContractId == NULL))) {
        opportunitiesToEvaluate.add(opp.Id); // Opportunity was not related to a contract but now is related to a contract
        System.debug('Count of this *OPPORTUNITY SET* is: ' + opportunitiesToEvaluate.size());  
        }
    }   

    if (!opportunitiesToEvaluate.isEmpty()) {

        // query only Opportunities which have >=1 Quote__c child records  

        Map<Id, Quote__c> oppToQuoteMap = new Map<Id, Quote__c>([SELECT Opportunity__c FROM Quote__c WHERE Opportunity__c IN : opportunitiesToEvaluate]);

        Set<Id> setQuoteOppIds = new Set<Id>();
        for(Quote__c objQ : [SELECT Opportunity__c FROM Quote__c WHERE Opportunity__c IN : opportunitiesToEvaluate])
        {
            setQuoteOppIds.add(objQ.Opportunity__c);
        }
        System.debug('Count of *SETQUOTEOPPIDS is: ' + setQuoteOppIds.size());

        System.debug('Count of this *MAP (oppToQuoteMap)* is: ' + oppToQuoteMap.size());

        // store the ContractId of all such Opportunities 
        Map<Id, Opportunity> oppToContractMap = new Map<Id, Opportunity>([SELECT Id, ContractId FROM Opportunity WHERE Id IN : setQuoteOppIds]);
        System.debug('Count of this *MAP* (oppToContractMap) is: ' + oppToQuoteMap.size());

        List<Attachment> attachmentsRelatedToOpps = [SELECT Id, ParentId, Name, Body FROM Attachment WHERE ParentId IN : setQuoteOppIds]; 

        for (Attachment file : attachmentsRelatedToOpps) {
            System.debug('Count of the *ATTACHMENT SET* is: ' + attachmentsRelatedToOpps.size());   
            Attachment newFile = file.clone(); 
            newFile.ParentId = oppToContractMap.get(file.ParentId).ContractId; 
            newFile.Name = file.Name;
            newFile.Body = file.Body;
            attachmentsToClone.add(newFile); 
            System.debug('Count of the *ATTACHMENT TO CLONE SET* is: ' + attachmentsToClone.size()); 
        }
    }

    insert attachmentsToClone; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please see the updated code below : Highlighted lines are wrong in your code
in this query you are fetching opportunity by using the quote ids that is the reason opportunity are not getting fetched.

**Map oppToContractMap = new Map([SELECT Id, ContractId FROM Opportunity WHERE Id IN : oppToQuoteMap.keySet()]);**

```
trigger CopyAttachmentsFromOpportunitiesWithDataSchedulesToContracts on Opportunity (after update, after insert) {

    Set<Id> opportunitiesToEvaluate = new Set<Id>(); 
    List<Attachment> attachmentsToClone = new List<Attachment>();

    for (Opportunity opp : Trigger.new) {
        if ((Trigger.isInsert && opp.ContractId != NULL) || (Trigger.isUpdate && (opp.ContractId != NULL && Trigger.oldMap.get(opp.Id).ContractId == NULL))) {
        opportunitiesToEvaluate.add(opp.Id); // Opportunity was not related to a contract but now is related to a contract
        System.debug('Count of this *OPPORTUNITY SET* is: ' + opportunitiesToEvaluate.size());  
        }
    }   

    if (!opportunitiesToEvaluate.isEmpty()) {

        // query only Opportunities which have >=1 Quote__c child records  

        Set<Id> setQuoteOppIds = new Set<Id>();
        for(Quote__c objQ : [SELECT Opportunity__c FROM Quote__c WHERE Opportunity__c IN : opportunitiesToEvaluate])
        {
            setQuoteOppIds.add(objQ.Opportunity__c);
        }

        System.debug('Count of this *MAP (oppToQuoteMap)* is: ' + oppToQuoteMap.size());

        // store the ContractId of all such Opportunities 
        Map<Id, Opportunity> oppToContractMap = new Map<Id, Opportunity>([SELECT Id, ContractId FROM Opportunity WHERE Id IN : setQuoteOppIds]);
        System.debug('Count of this *MAP* (oppToContractMap) is: ' + oppToQuoteMap.size());

        List<Attachment> attachmentsRelatedToOpps = [SELECT Id, ParentId FROM Attachment WHERE ParentId IN : oppToQuoteMap.keySet()]; 

        for (Attachment file : attachmentsRelatedToOpps) {
            System.debug('Count of the *ATTACHMENT SET* is: ' + attachmentsRelatedToOpps.size());   
            Attachment newFile = file.clone(); 
            newFile.ParentId = oppToContractMap.get(file.ParentId).ContractId; 
            attachmentsToClone.add(newFile); 
            System.debug('Count of the *ATTACHMENT TO CLONE SET* is: ' + attachmentsToClone.size()); 
        }
    }

    insert attachmentsToClone; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your review. this trigger still isn't working. Once I relate a contract to an opportunity which has >=1 quote record, then the Attachments from the Opportunity aren't being cloned against the Contract.

Comment: can you please check the debug for **setQuoteOppIds**?

Comment: Sure. I get a count of 1 for the setQuoteOppIds set, and all the other debug counts are 1 except for the last 2 (ATTACHMENT SET and ATTACHMENT TO CLONE SET).